# Application.Wait and Excel VBA Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I don't understand why I have this row ***Application.Wait*** in error (highlighted in yellow) ?

```
Sub Wait_Random()
Dim Low As Double
Dim High As Double
Low = 90 '<<< CHANGE AS DESIRED
High = 126 '<<< CHANGE AS DESIRED
r = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & CStr(r))
End Sub
```

I have found that the problem is that this code is trying "to add a number to a string of characters". But I am lost ! Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your `r` variable always greater than `59` sec. (actually it's alwasys greater 90). You should change `Low` and `High` so that `r` would never be greater 59:

```
Sub Wait_Random()
    Dim Low As Double
    Dim High As Double
    Dim r as Integer
    Low = 1 '<<< CHANGE AS DESIRED
    High = 59 '<<< CHANGE AS DESIRED
    r = Int((High - Low) * Rnd() + Low)
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:" & CStr(r))
End Sub
```

Or another way you could use

```
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", r, Now)
```

to add `r` seconds. In that case `r` could be greater `59`.

Comment: Thanks.;) Your fist answer works fine ;) The second one does not seems to work on excel 2003. Don't worry I keep the first one. ;) Many thanks again. ;)

Comment: Strange - just tested it in Excel 2003 and it works:) btw, glad it helps!

Comment: Same problem on my part for the second solution (it works fine the first time and the next time it seems to be blocked)...Well, please don't worry. ;) Thanks ;). BTW, I have seen that you have removed the +1 of the first solution. Thanks. ;)

Comment: @Erb, found my error:) see updated answer. When using `Application.Wait Now + r` - we add `r` *days*. To add `r` seconds use `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", r, Now)`

Comment: Hi, Many thanks. ;) I can can confirm that your last code is working too with more than 59 seconds. ;) Thank you again. ;)